# query on embedded mongodb->documents (objects)

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this structure:

```
{
 "_id": NumberInt(101),
"link_id": {
"125": {
"thumb_position": NumberInt(1),
"last_scan": NumberInt(1234563645),
"row_numb": NumberInt(301),
"clicks": NumberInt(120)
},
"126": {
 "thumb_position": NumberInt(2),
 "last_scan": NumberInt(-2147483648),
 "row_numb": NumberInt(1301),
 "clicks": NumberInt(199)
   },
   {
...
   }
}
}
```

the thing is I want to query by _id and link_id. I've tried in PHP:

```
 $arr_ = array("_id" => intval(101), "link_id" => "125");
 $res = $collection->findOne($arr_);
```

and many other variant and no results. If I only search for the _id everything works. Any ideas? Thx a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the link_id 125 is not a value I see two options:

a) Use [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/) operator:

```
$arr_ = array(
    "_id" => intval(101),
    "link_id" => array("125" => array('$exists' => true))
);
```

b) Change your structure and use a slightly different query:

```
{
    "_id": NumberInt(101),
    "link": [
        {
            "id": "125",
            "thumb_position": NumberInt(1),
            "last_scan": NumberInt(1234563645),
            "row_numb": NumberInt(301),
            "clicks": NumberInt(120)
        },{
            "id": "126",
            …
       }
    ]
}
```

…

```
$arr_ = array(
    "_id" => intval(101),
    "link" => array("id" => "125")
);
```

Not tested but it should work in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, a better schema here is to convert it to an array of objects rather than an object of objects, however, to answer:

```
$arr_ = array("_id" => intval(101), "link_id.125" => array('$exists' => true));
```

This will check for where that element exists as a key for the `link_id` subdocuments using `$exists` : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/